# Formulas for different permutation/combination scenarios

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was trying to develop formulas for different permutation/combination scenarios, but I could not sort out last three cases. Please check these following cases -

---

### Unique items

1. Repetition: **no**

   - Permutation: $_nP_r$
   - Combination: $_nC_r$
2. Repetition: **yes**

   - Permutation: $n^r$
   - Combination: $_{n+r-1}C_r$ ***or*** $_{n+r-1}C_{n-1}$

---

### Non-unique items

1. Repetition: **no**

   - Permutation: $\displaystyle \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}$, where $k_1,k_2,\dots k_n$ are numbers of non-unique items
   - Combination: ??
2. Repetition: **yes**

   - Permutation: ??
   - Combination: ??

Comment: I messed up part of my edit in the non-unique items section. Sorry about that.

Comment: Notice that the formula you give for permutations of non-unique items assumes that we take all $n$ items. As such, it is not completely analogous to the formulas you presented for unique items. If we continue to take all items, for example, then there will only be one combination of non-unique (or unique) items.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Closely related with your question is a somewhat more general consideration of fundamental counting techniques called

> **The twelvefold way**
>
> R.P. Stanley presents in his classic *[Enumerative combinatorics](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf)* vol. 1 in section 1.9 the so-called    *twelvefold way*.  He considers finite  sets   $N$  and $X$, with $|N|=n,  |X|=x$ and counts the  number of different  functions      $f:N\rightarrow  X$   under different situations.

- *Functions:* $f$ may be arbitrary, injective or surjective giving three different possibilities.
- *Sets:* Elements of $N,X$ may be either distinguishable or indistinguishable resulting in four different possibilities.

> Altogether we can consider $3\cdot 4=12$ different situations:
>
> \begin{array}{ll|ccc}
> \text{elements }N&\text{elements }X&\quad\text{any }f\quad&\quad\text{injective }f\quad&\quad\text{surjective } f\quad\\
> \hline
> \text{dist.}&\text{dist.}&x^n\quad&\quad x^{\underline{n}}\quad&x!{n\brace x}\\
> \text{indist.}&\text{dist.}&\left(\!\!{x\choose n}\!\!\right)\quad&\quad\binom{x}{n}\quad&\left(\!\!{x\choose n-x}\!\!\right)\quad\\
> \text{dist.}&\text{indist.}&\sum_{j=0}^x{n\brace j}\quad&\quad\begin{matrix}1&\text{if }n\leq x\\0&\text{if }n>x\end{matrix}\quad&{n\brace x}\quad\\
> \text{indist.}&\text{indist.}&\sum_{j=0}^xp_j(n)\quad&\quad\begin{matrix}1&\text{if }n\leq x\\0&\text{if }n>x\end{matrix}\quad&p_x(n)\quad\\
> \end{array}

with

$\qquad x^{\underline{n}}=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$ the *[falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)* of $x$,

$\qquad x!=x(x-1)\cdots 3\cdot2\cdot1$    the *[factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)* of $x$,

$\qquad \binom{x}{n}=\frac{x!}{n!(x-n)!}$ the *[binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)* $x$ choose $n$,

$\qquad \left(\!\!{x\choose n}\!\!\right)=\binom{x+n-1}{n}$ the number of *[multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets)* $x$ multichoose $n$.

$\qquad {n\brace x}$ the *[Stirling numbers of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)* and

$\qquad p_x(n)$ the number of *[partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))* of $n$ into $x$ parts.

A presentation in terms of urns and balls can be found *[here](http://www.johndcook.com/TwelvefoldWay.pdf)*.

> **[2016-10-15] Add-on:**
>
> Some information regarding properties of functions and sets added due to a comment of OP.
>
> A function $f:N\rightarrow X$ is said to be
>
> - *arbitrary* or *non-restrictive* if there is no specific restriction given
> - *[injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)* or *one-to-one* if each element of $X$ is the image of *at most* one element of $N$
> - *[surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function)* or *onto* if each element of $X$ is the image of *at least* one element of $N$

*Examples:* Let's take a look at some functions with respect to these properties:

> \begin{array}{l|ccc}
> \text{function}&arbitrary&injective&surjective\\
> \hline
> \\
> f:\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow\{a,b,c,d\}&\mathbb{\color{blue}{\text{yes}}}&-&-\\
> f(1)=f(2)=c,f(3)=a\\
> \\
> g:\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow\{a,b,c,d\}&\mathbb{\color{blue}{\text{yes}}}&\mathbb{\color{blue}{\text{yes}}}&-\\
> g(1)=d,g(2)=c,g(3)=a\\
> \\
> h:\{1,2,3,4\}\rightarrow\{a,b,c\}&\mathbb{\color{blue}{\text{yes}}}&-&\mathbb{\color{blue}{\text{yes}}}\\
> h(1)=h(4)=c,h(2)=a,h(3)=b\\
> \\
> i:\{1,2,3,4\}\rightarrow\{a,b,c,d\}&\mathbb{\color{blue}{\text{yes}}}&\mathbb{\color{blue}{\text{yes}}}&\mathbb{\color{blue}{\text{yes}}}\\
> i(1)=d,i(2)=c,i(3)=a,i(4)=b\\
> \end{array}

**Balls and boxes**

We think of $N=\{1,2,3\}$ as a set of balls and of $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ as a set of boxes. A function $f:N\rightarrow X$ is considered as  placing each ball into some box.

> We consider four functions $j,k,l,m: N\rightarrow X$ by
>   \begin{array}{lclcllcl}
> j(1)&=&j(2)&=&a,&\qquad j(3)&=&b\\
> k(1)&=&k(3)&=&a,&\qquad k(2)&=&b\\
> l(1)&=&l(2)&=&b,&\qquad l(3)&=&d\\
> m(2)&=&m(3)&=&b,&\qquad m(1)&=&c\\
> \end{array}

**Four functions with distinguishable balls and boxes:**

[image]

**with balls indistinguishable:**

[image]

**with boxes indistinguishable:**

[image]

**with balls and boxes indistinguishable:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this seems too good for me now for now and will take a great amount of time to normalize those into "readable" equations. However, could you please explain a bit about what these terms "arbitrary, injective or surjective" mean.

Comment: @neo-nant: I've added some information which might be helpful.