# N balls in r urns

Tags: combinatorics

Could someone please explain the difference between these two cases:
1. No. Of ways to arrange n distinguishable balls in r urns.
2. No. Of ways to arrange n balls in r urns when the balls are identical.

It would be great if someone could explain them taking specific values of n and r.

Comment: The difference between the two cases... take two balls and two urns.,  the balls are labeled $A$ and $B$, and the urns are represented by brackets and location.,  $[A][B]$ is considered a different outcome than $[B][A]$.  For the balls being identical, these are considered to be the same outcome as they are both $[\star][\star]$.

Comment: @JMoravitz why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @NathanielMayer because someone will inevitably downvote his perfectly fine answer just because the question is ill worded :/

Comment: @Nathaniel really, if anything it was because that would legitimize this as being a good enough question to properly answer, which I don't think it is.

Comment: Missing from the Question is whether the *urns* are distinguishable or not (i.e. identical urns).

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* We should also consider if *urns* are distinguishable or not. If this is not explicitly stated, we typically assume they are *indistinguishable* (but should state this assumption in an answer).  Here is an example with $n=3$ balls and $r=4$ urns.

> We think of $N=\{1,2,3\}$ as a set of balls and of $R=\{a,b,c,d\}$ as a set of urns. A function $f:N\rightarrow R$ is considered as  placing each ball into some urn.
>
> We consider four functions $j,k,l,m: N\rightarrow R$ by
>   \begin{array}{lclcllcl}
> j(1)&=&j(2)&=&a,&\qquad j(3)&=&b\\
> k(1)&=&k(3)&=&a,&\qquad k(2)&=&b\\
> l(1)&=&l(2)&=&b,&\qquad l(3)&=&d\\
> m(2)&=&m(3)&=&b,&\qquad m(1)&=&c\\
> \end{array}

*Four functions with distinguishable balls and urns:*

[image]

*with balls indistinguishable:*

[image]

*with urns indistinguishable:*

[image]

*with balls and urns indistinguishable:*

[image]

*Note:* Some more information is given in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962802/formulas-for-different-permutation-combination-scenarios/1968082#1968082)*.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, let's make it simple and consider 2 balls and 2 urns. Have the balls be labeled X and Y, respectfully. Since in the first case the balls are not identical, this means that the probability of choosing X is not equal to choosing Y. The these events are not equally probable, no matter in what urns they are pulled from. In the second case, we have balls X and Y, which are identical. This means that the probability of choosing X then Y is the same as choosing Y then X afterwards. The key thing to remember is the word **identical**.

Answer (score -1):

Both the balls and the urns are distinguishable

$n=1,r=1$ gives $1!$ ways

$n=2,r=2$ gives $2!$ ways

$n=6,r=10$ you have a choice of selecting 6 urns from 10 and then put the balls in them that gives you $10\choose6$.$6!$

In case of balls being identical you can disting which ball went in to which urn so if $n=6,r=10$
the answer is just $10\choose 6$

Comment: $10$ urns, $6$ balls, all distinguishable, there are $10^{6}$ ways to arrange.  Balls indistinguishable urns distinguishable there are $\binom{15}{5}$ ways.  Balls distinguishable urns indistinguishable there are $\sum\limits_{r=1}^6\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}10\\r\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ ways... none of which match your given answers.  Remember that multiple balls can go to the same urn, you are not limited to just one ball per urn.